# Should suicide tag be synonym of selfdestruct?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

The OPCODE [suicide](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suicide) is deprecated in favour for [selfdestruct](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selfdestruct), [see](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1304/87).

For reference, let's make the [suicide](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suicide) tag a synonym of [selfdestruct](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selfdestruct)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with this and you are correct that SUICIDE is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

Agree.  Think we may need to add the [support](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) to this question.